Why does my clothes dryer sometimes fail to start?
My older dryer (Kenmore 110 series electric dryer) was working fine and would start right up when the button was pressed and dry the clothes. Recently (past few weeks) it has become flaky, and will now inhabit one of 3 states.

Press start button and the dryer will just buzz and not start

If I’ve left it for a while, maybe turned the circuit breaker off/on or unplugged it and plugged it back in, if I press and hold the start button, it will buzz for a second or two then actually start. At this point it may or may not complete the cycle. If it stops in the middle, it most likely has reverted to state 1.

If it’s not been starting and just buzzing, if I try too many times (maybe spin the drum by hand), it can reach this state where pressing the button will do nothing at all (no buzz no start). Unplugging/replugging or toggling the circuit breaker and waiting a bit can get it back to state 1 or 2.


If it starts, it heats up just fine.  I’ve tested the following, but have not been able to resolve the issue…

the belt looked fine, but I put on a new one just in case - because at one point the dryer was making whining noises.

I cleaned lint from everywhere I could access, including exhaust hose.

I checked motor and it spins easily when the belt is detached

I tested the connectivity of the door switch and the start button (both fine)


It might be a good idea to just invest in a new dryer, but money is tight right now so it would be better if I can fix it and keep it going for a while longer. Any ideas of what might be wrong and how to fix it appreciated. Thanks.

What's the age of the dryer?    Does the dryer normally make tones for end-of-cycle?    Mine for instance buzzes for end-of-cycle, so I'd be looking at a sensor if it started buzzing inappropriately.

I'd lean toward checking the motor's start capacitor and connected wiring.
AC motors need a start capacitor to get spinning, otherwise they just sit there and buzz. In many motors, like the push-button-start motor in a typical dryer, the start capacitor is only supposed to be connected while the motor starts spinning up. Once the motor is up to a required rotational speed, the start capacitor should be removed from power. Thus the start capacitor is connected via a momentary push button. As long as the button is held down, the start capacitor is connected to get the motor spinning. Once the button is released, the start capacitor is disconnected.
In your situation, the start capacitor either is not good anymore (they do go bad sometimes) or there is a loose electrical connection.

That sounds very plausible.  Is this something that I can test for?  If it is the start capacitor, is there a way to replace that part, or would I replace the entire motor?  It looks like I might be able to get a replacement motor for this dryer for ~$65, which seems reasonable.

It's rather likely that the start capacitor is a separate part that is a lot less expensive than the motor. It should be easily replaceable. These capacitors often are attached with spade connectors. Get on a parts website and find the start capacitor, then buy and replace it.
